# Define Variable within a Handler Function using gWidgets?

Tags: r

I need to define a variable based on input from a radio button from gWidgets. The simple conceptual version of what I would like to do is below, where the variable "gas" takes on "CO" or "CO2" based on the radio button input at the time "Save Choice" is clicked:

```
gasw <- gwindow("Gas")
gasg <- ggroup(container= gasw)
gasr <- gradio(c("CO2","CO"),container=gasw)
gasbu <- gbutton("Save Choice",border = T,container = gasw,handler = function(h,...){
  dispose(gasw)
})
addHandlerClicked(gasr, handler=function(h,..) {
gas <- svalue(h$obj)
})
```

More specifically, I need to define "gas" as a vector of characters and not just "CO" or "CO2":

```
gas <- c("CO2", "CO2_response", "CO2_ppm", "CO2_calibrated")
```

or

```
gas <- c("CO", "CO_response", "CO_ppm", "CO_calibrated")
```

But I cannot define even a simple variable in a handler function. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: You are bumping up against the fact that within a function call you can't define a variable (introduce a side effect) without some extra work. You have options though: use <<- to assign to a global; use an environment; use the global environment and assign, as in `assign("gas", svalue(h$obj), .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: Adding the .GlobalEnv fixed this! It takes some time to load in the Global Environment, but it works.